# Constantly logging to a file with Cordova-WebApp on Win 8.1/WinJS

Tags: cordova, logging, web-applications, winjs

What would be the best way to constantly write to a logfile without using the internal logging system (LoggingSession)? I did something like:

```
function raisedWhenNewLogMessageArrived(message) {
        var fileName = getcurrentDate() + ".log";

        var appDataDir = WinJS.Application.local.folder;
        appDataDir.getFolderAsync("log", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.openIfExists).then(
            function (folder) {
                folder.createFileAsync(fileName, Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.openIfExists).then(
                    function (file) {
                        Windows.Storage.FileIO.appendTextAsync(file,message + "\n").then(
                                    function () {
                                        win("OK");
                                    },
                                    function (e) {
                                        fail(e);
                                    });
                    },
                            function (e) {
                                fail(e);
                            })
            },
                    function (e) {
                        fail(e);
                    }
                    );
}
```

But of course this crashes if there are a lot of incoming log messages (at startup around 800). I also tried to keep the file opened constantly and write to it, but this crashes also. Would something like FileOutputStream be the better option? How would I use it?

Thanks in advance any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest separating all the code up to FileIO.appendTextAsync so that you cache a StorageFile object. A StorageFile is really just an abstraction for a pathname to allow for files that aren't actually backed by the file system. Keeping a StorageFile in hand, then, does not mean that you're holding the file open. FileIO.appendTextAsync will take care of opening a stream, writing to it, and closing it.

So you can do the getFolderAsync and createFileAsync once instead of doing it with every message. Then I suspect that the appendTextAsync will be able to keep up with your logging traffic. Given that WinRT is written to be thread-safe, the implementation of appendTextAsync should handle concurrency matters just fine. You logging method, then, is just a simple wrapper around appendTextAsync using your cached StorageFile object.

As an alternative, check out the FileLoggingSession class in Windows.Foundation.Diagnostics, which is written exactly to do continuous file-based logging, and also generates binary RTL data that can be brought into the Windows Performance Analyzer and Trace Reporter tools in the Windows SDK. For details, see the [FileLoggingSession sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/FileLoggingSession-Sample-2bc103d9) and the [Windows Performance Analyzer documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh448170.aspx).